# data.filter is not function angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

[image]I use factory get data in file but it not working . Here is my code

```
.factory('dataServices',dataServices);

        dataServices.$inject =['$http'];

        function dataServices($http){
            var services = {    
                getType    :getType
            }
            return services;
function getType(){
                return $http.get('/src/server/data/data.php')
                .then(function(response){
                    return response.data.filter(function(item){
                        return item.loai;
                    });
                })
            }
```

Here is code in controller

```
Shell.$inject =['dataServices'];

            function Shell(dataServices){
                var vm = this;
                vm.types=dataServices.getType();
                console.log(vm.types) 
            }
```

Here is file php

```
  ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    require '/../server/connectdb.php';
    $row = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM item";
    if($result){
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Here is my json file

```
   [{"id":"1","masp":"CPUB028","tensp":"Block CPU EK Supre","hangsx":"INTEL","loai":"CPU","img":"item1.jpg","gia":"70","gt":null},

{"id":"2","masp":"CPUIT5","tensp":"CPU INTEL CORE I5","hangsx":"INTEL","loai":"CPU","img":"item14.jpg","gia":"400","gt":null}]
```

In console.log I get response.data.filter is not funtion. Where is my wrong?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter check out the docs, iirc, angular has a special filter function

Comment: try to log response to see if you have a data object  into

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that might be going wrong here:

- Check if your json is being served with a `application/json` content-type
- Make sure there is no whitespace at the start of the JSON response

One of these conditions needs to be true for angular to think it's supposed to parse the json file: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L140

Your console.log won't work, since $http returns a promise, so you would need to do something like `dataServices.getType().then(console.log)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the code in your factory method of getType() as shown as below,

```
   return $http.get('/src/server/data/data.php').then(function(response){
      var returnValue = [];
      angular.forEach(response.data.value, function(item){
         returnValue.push(item.loai);
      });
      return returnValue;
   }
```

Comment: I get array[321] in console.log and all is underfine

Comment: can you share your console.log(response.data) data sample?

Comment: I add picture in question . When i change to `response` instead `response.data` , it get success 5 item (i have 5 item) , but all is undefine

Comment: As per your screenshot you may need to add value from you response data as like response.data.value. I've update my answer try and let me know..